# UI5 i18n support for the static model data

Tags: sapui5

I'm exploring the [`sap.f.ProductSwitch`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.f.ProductSwitch) controller on a sample project [`sap.f.sample.ShellBarProductSwitch`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.f.ProductSwitch/sample/sap.f.sample.ShellBarProductSwitch).

Everything is clear besides one thing, what should be the approach if I want to provide an `i18n` support for a list of products (`model/data.json`)?

E.g. additionally to the hardcoded English list of products:

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "src": "sap-icon://home",
            "title": "Home"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to provide a Frech one:

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "src": "sap-icon://home",
            "title": "Maison"
        }
    ]
}
```

With a basic dialogues I can rely on the built-in `i18n` UI5-engine, but here I don't know how to enable `i18n` in an XML-template:

```xml
<f:ProductSwitchItem
    src = "{src}"
    title = "{title}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like the data binding approach better, you can use a formatter with the title property binding to retrieve the text from the resource model.

The key to the text of the resource bundle must be defined in your data.json for every item:

The JSON data model:

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "src": "sap-icon://home",
            "titleI18NKey": "myResourceBundleKeyToThisItem"
        }
    ]
}
```

The XML-template:

```xml
<ProductSwitch
    change = "onClickProductSwitcherItem"
    items = "{
        path: '/items'
    }">

    <items>

        <ProductSwitchItem
            src = "{src}"
            title = "{
                path: 'titleI18NKey',
                formatter: '.getText'
        }" />

    </items>

</ProductSwitch>
```

The formatter `getText` needs to be defined in your controller:

```js
getText(i18nKey) {

    const dialogue = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getProperty(i18nKey);

    return dialogue;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A home-made solution.

XML-template:

```xml
<f:ProductSwitchItem
    src = "{src}"
    title = "{titleI18NKey}" />
```

Controller:

```js
const resourceBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();

const productSwitcherModelData = this.getView().getModel("productSwitcher")?.getData();

productSwitcherModelData.items.forEach((item) => {

    item.titleI18NKey = resourceBundle.getText(item.titleI18NKey);

});

this.productSwitcher.setModel(this.getView().getModel("productSwitcher"));
```

In product switcher model instead of real text I store a key-value pair:

```js
titleI18NKey: i18n_dialogue_key
```

which is later replaced by the end-text from the `i18n`-model and set to the `productSwitcher` model.

P.S. Please, let me know, if there is more elegant implementation based on UI5 functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have static values I would rather not use list binding but create the product switch items individually:

```
<ProductSwitch change="fnChange" >
   <items>                                              
      <ProductSwitchItem src="sap-icon://retail-store" title="{i18n>Title_1}" />
      <ProductSwitchItem src="sap-icon://family-care" title="{i18n>Title_2}" />
   </items>
</ProductSwitch >
```

In doing so you can use the resource model for the titles as usual and don't need any further code.

Comment: Do you mean to create a `ProductSwitchItems` model, which should be bound to the `ProductSwitch` UI controller?

Comment: No, just use the `ProductSwitch` control without a model as in the example.

Comment: I've checked the [`ProductSwitch`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.f.ProductSwitch/sample/sap.f.sample.ShellBarProductSwitch) sample and there we can see a [`model/data.json`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.fmodel/data.json), in my opinion, it's more proper solution, since it extracts the items to a separate JSON, which can be easily maintained without touching a codebase.